# Issue with uploading file from local file system to php server

Tags: php, html, file

I am trying on upload file from local file system to a remote server using php.

I am using move_uploaded_file function but when i select a file on my local file system, it tries to find the file on remote server and hence fails. maybe i am missing something. Let's say if i am trying to upload a file from C:\Data\abc.txt. It tries to find the file on /server/abc.txt and hence fails to upload the file. Please let me know if i am missing something.

```
<?
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
        $original = $root_path .$file_name; 

        echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        if($file_size > 100097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 100 MB';
        }

        if(empty($errors)==true){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/uploads');
            echo "Success";
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    } 
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if I have understood you correctly, but you means with remote server your webserver? 
This server doesnt access your file system directly because of your browser's sandbox mode. It gets only the submitted file, the origin path doesnt matter.

The second parameter of the function *move_uploaded_file* has to be the target file, not the target dictionary.

Example:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '/uploads/' . $file_name);
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue :) a silly mistake from my end. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

diffcult to answer pls tell me the php version and as a hint: have you checked is_uploaded_file() php.net/manual/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 1):

could help to use the error/status-reporting in $_FILES['image']['error'] - gives feedback on error/status code of your file upload, so you can better understand what the source of the problem possibly is:

```
0 = success
1 = file too big (php.ini set)
2 = file too big (max file size directive)
4 = no file was uploaded
6 = no access to temp folder on server
7 = file could not be written to server
8 = upload stopped by a php extension
```

hope that helps